# What does the absolute value of an operator mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

In the text, we are given a Hamiltonian for two bodies with a potential energy of interaction that depends on the magnitude of the distance between them as:

$$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{1}^{2}}{2 m_{1}}+\frac{\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{2}^{2}}{2 m_{2}}+V\left(\left|\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{1}-\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{2}\right|\right).$$

What does the absolute value of an operator mean and how does it operate and why?

Comment: Taking the absolute value just works like applying any other function to an operator (e.g. the potential $V$!). Are you familiar with how it works for other functions and there's something special about the absolute value you can't figure out, or is how to apply functions to operators actually the question here?

Comment: For example, I understand that taking the square of an operator gives us another operator which when applied to a state, would give the same result if we were to apply the former operator twice. In this sense, how does the absolute value work?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263303/50583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any quantum mechanical observable $\hat O$ so that  $$\hat O|\psi⟩=o|\psi⟩$$ with eigenvalue $o$. Then for any function $f$ of the observable $\hat O$ we have, $$f(\hat O) \mid\psi\rangle = f(o) \mid\psi\rangle$$

The same applies for a function of the absolute value operator. So if we consider $V(\mid\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{1}-\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{2}|)$ and the two-particle state $\mid \psi(\mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{r_2})\rangle$ then $$V(\mid\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{1}-\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{2}|)\mid \psi(\mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{r_2})\rangle=V(\mid{\mathbf{r}}_{1}-{\mathbf{r}}_{2}\mid)\mid \psi(\mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{r_2})\rangle$$ where the potential on the RHS is now a function of the eigenvalue $(\mid{\mathbf{r}}_{1}-{\mathbf{r}}_{2}\mid)$.

Comment: Your $|r\rangle$ should be a two-particle state, no?

Comment: so $|\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}||\boldsymbol{r}\rangle=|\boldsymbol{r}||\boldsymbol{r}\rangle$ ?

Comment: is $|\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}||\boldsymbol{r}\rangle=|\boldsymbol{r}||\boldsymbol{r}\rangle$ correct if $\hat{r}|\mathbf{r}\rangle=\boldsymbol{r}|\boldsymbol{r}\rangle$ ? (sorry the last operator r is also in vector form)

Comment: Yes, that is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

If an operator $A$ is *normal*$^\ddagger$ - that is, $[A^\dagger,A]=0$ - it admits a [spectral decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Normal_matrices) of the form
$$A = \sum_i \lambda_i |\lambda_i\rangle\langle\lambda_i| $$
where the $\lambda_i$ are its (possibly generalized) eigenvalues, the $|\lambda_i\rangle$ its (possibly generalized) eigenvectors, and the sum may be replaced by an integral if the spectrum of $A$ is continuous.  In such cases, given a function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$, one may define the operator $\hat f(A)$ to be

$$\hat f(A):= \sum_i f(\lambda_i) |\lambda_i \rangle\langle \lambda_i|$$

In particular, this holds for the absolute value function.

It's possible to generalize this construction beyond normal operators by noting that for *any*$^{\ddagger\ddagger}$ $A$, the operator $A^\dagger A$ is self-adjoint (and therefore normal) and in fact positive, such that
$$A^\dagger A = \sum_i \Lambda_i |\Lambda_i\rangle\langle \Lambda_i| , \qquad \Lambda_i \in[0,\infty)$$
That being the case, we are able to apply the square-root function to $A^\dagger A$.  From here, we define $|A|$ to be
$$|A| := \sqrt{A^\dagger A} = \sum_i \sqrt{\Lambda_i} |\Lambda_i \rangle\langle \Lambda_i|$$

As an example of the latter general construction, consider the absolute value of the creation operator $a^\dagger$ from the quantum harmonic oscillator problem.  $[a,a^\dagger]\neq 0$ so it is not normal, but $ aa^\dagger = 1+ a^\dagger a = 1 + N$ where
$$N = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n | n\rangle\langle n|$$
is the number operator.  By definition then, we have that
$$|a^\dagger| := \sqrt{aa^\dagger} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{1+n}|n\rangle\langle n|$$
Note that $a^\dagger$ has no eigenvalues or eigenvectors, so one cannot define its absolute value spectrally. This definition of the absolute value of an operator is used in the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of an operator.

---

$^\ddagger$ Familiar examples of normal operators are self-adjoint operators, for which $A^\dagger = A$, and unitary operators, for which $A^\dagger = A^{-1}$.

$^{\ddagger\ddagger}$The usual subtleties and caveats (domain issues, etc) apply if the operator is unbounded, but the moral of the story remains the same.